# Ожидание появление записи mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Нужно, чтобы скрипт ждал когда появится запись в таблице с конкретным id
Пробую так но работает неверно:

```
while(!$res_round = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `test_table` WHERE id = 4461")){

echo 'sleep';
sleep(1);
}

echo 'Запись есть!';
```

Может это можно на чистом SQL сделать

Answer (score 0):

Если скрипт будет ждать дольше, чем установлен таймаут в php.ini, с вероятностью в 101% нагрянет 500 ошибка. Правильнее будет делать асинхронные запросы из фронтенда, и проверять, появилась ли запись

Comment: ожидание может длится до 5 секунд, так что надо решать проблему именно так)